# Non-Systemd Based Linux Services

Tags: linux, service

I am running AntiX in a virtual machine.

I have a service (python script) that I wrote that I was able to set up as 'auto start' on boot. It works fine.
However, when the service crashes (or is commanded by my server to restart), it does not auto start... What do I need to do to get it to auto start?

I have searched for two days and cannot find a definitive answer.

NOTE: this is NOT a systemd based Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you either use a dedicated supervisor daemon/process that you ensure starts at boot and that in turn starts, monitors and restarts other processes/daemons.

Traditionally in Linux that is also "init", which comes in a number of flavours. AntiX provides you with two init system flavours: sysVinit and runit.

Both of them should offer you the ability to start daemons at boot and restart failed daemons.

Wikipedia provides a fairly comprehensive list of additional (non init as well as init) supervisors : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision

Answer (score 0):

You may try [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html). It supports different restart conditions, dependencies, etc.